# @MainActor is not guaranteeing to execute code in the main thread

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

I'm using the native ASWebAuthenticationSession to do a web-view based authentication and I 'm getting this runtime warning with corresponding console output:

*Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIWindow init]
PID: 15042, TID: 2317190, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative, QoS: 25*

[image]

So I have added the @MainActor attribute to the method but it has no effect. still  getting the same warning and same console output:

*Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIWindow init]
PID: 15476, TID: 2328029, Thread name: (none), Queue name: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos.cooperative, QoS: 25*

[image]

Am I missing something? where I can find

Comment: The `@MainActor` attribute is only applicable when you call that method from your code. You can’t just decorate some delegate method with `@MainActor` and expect it to run on the main thread…

Comment: I don’t know this API, but I’m surprised that this is getting called one anything but the main thread, already. I might go back earlier in the flow and see if you are initiating this process from something other than the main queue. I suspect that there is not enough here for us to [reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your problem…

Comment: To put it another way: This is not `async` code so talking about `@MainActor` is pointless. If the problem is that `ASPresentationAnchor()` needs to be called on the main thread, hey, this is your code, call it on the main thread.

Comment: This is odd. I didn't use this framework for a while, but I remember the implementation was exactly like yours, nothing else was needed (no main thread, and no main actor). Here's a detailed example which also confirms that: https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/using-aswebauthenticationaession-swiftui/ Could it be related to how you use ASWebAuthenticationSession rather? Or did it start happening on specific version? could be a bug, worth posting on apple forum IMO

Comment: @Rob and matt  Thanks for input. I was creating an ASWebAuthenticationSession  from a (non mainActor viewModel object) And I knew that declaring the view model MainActor would resolve the problem. But I was just trying to limit the scope of the MaiActor But if the delegate method is not called from an async context I understand that it wouldn't work. But how do I know that the delegate method is not called from an async context? and even if I create the ASWebAuthenticationSession from a MainActor context, I cannot assume that the delegate will be called from a Main actor?

Comment: “But how do I know that the delegate method is not called from an async context?” … As [SE-0316](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#introduction) says (emphasis added), “Swift actors achieve this with actor isolation, which ensures *(at compile time)* that all accesses to that instance data go through a synchronization mechanism that serializes execution.” It’s a compile-time mechanism. A framework (esp delegation pattern) can not dynamically determine to which actor you may have isolated your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Synchronous** methods run on the same thread as the caller *regardless of any actor annotations*. E.g:

```swift
func foo() {
    // this will run on whichever thread it's called from
}

@MainActor
func foo2() {
    // this will ignore @MainActor and also run on the same thread it's called from. 
    // if the caller is the main thread, it will run on the main thread.
    // if the caller is a background thread, it will run on the background thread.
}
```

When I first started learning about actors I thought `foo2` would be guaranteed to run on the main thread given it's annotated with `@MainActor` and the main actor's executor uses the main thread. What I didn't realise was that this only happens if the method is `async`. E.g.:

```swift
@MainActor
func foo3() async {
    // This is guaranteed to run on the main thread regardless of the caller's thread
}
```

Because `foo3` is marked as `async`, the call site's `Task` can suspend execution and give up its thread. This allows `foo3` to 'hop' onto a different actor if needed. In this example, `foo3` is explicitly annotated with `@MainActor` so it inherits that context.

Even if we used a method that wasn't annotated explicitly, it might still *implicitly* inherit an actor context. E.g.

```swift
@MainActor
class Bar {
    func foo4() async {
        // this implicitly inherits the actor context from `Bar`
    }
}
```

So `foo4` above would be isolated to the main actor and run on the main thread. But, if we removed `async` then it would run on the same thread as the caller and essentially ignore `Bar`'s `@MainActor` annotation.

If an `async` method isn't isolated to an actor, it will run on the default executor, which uses a pool of background threads. This means that it can run on a different thread even if it was called from the main thread. E.g.:

```swift
// inherits no actor context
func foo5() async {
    // this will run on a background thread (even when called from the main thread)
}
```

So, to answer your question directly: the `presentationAnchor(...)` method is ignoring the `@MainActor` annotation because the method is synchronous. It will run on the same thread as the call site, which in this case is a background thread.

To isolate it to the main actor and use the main thread, you could either:

i) keep the `@MainActor` annotation and mark the method with `async`. Or, if you can't modify the call site,
ii) manually place the code within the method on the main actor e.g. `Task { @MainActor ... }`.

Comment: You're missing some subtlety here. The key point is that Swift Concurrency is in large part a compile-time technology. foo2 will be called on the main thread - if the compiler 'realises' at compile time that this is required.
So - that covers most, (but not all) the code in your app - and none of the code in frameworks that you call (which potentially call back to your foo2)